# Installing "preview-generator" module in Python results in FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, pip

I am using Windows 10. I have both python 2.7 and 3.8. I'm trying to install this [module](https://pypi.org/project/preview-generator/#description) for version 3.8.

On cmd I'm entered:

```
pip3.8 install preview-generator
```

However, it fails to install. Here is the error log shown on cmd:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\avi and amit\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\AVI and AMIT\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zh7w977n\\pyexifinfo\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\AVI and AMIT\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zh7w977n\\pyexifinfo\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\AVI and AMIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zh7w977n\pyexifinfo\pip-egg-info'
     cwd: C:\Users\AVI and AMIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zh7w977n\pyexifinfo\
Complete output (21 lines):
running egg_info
creating C:\Users\AVI and AMIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zh7w977n\pyexifinfo\pip-egg-info\pyexifinfo.egg-info
writing C:\Users\AVI and AMIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zh7w977n\pyexifinfo\pip-egg-info\pyexifinfo.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to C:\Users\AVI and AMIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zh7w977n\pyexifinfo\pip-egg-info\pyexifinfo.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to C:\Users\AVI and AMIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zh7w977n\pyexifinfo\pip-egg-info\pyexifinfo.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'C:\Users\AVI and AMIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zh7w977n\pyexifinfo\pip-egg-info\pyexifinfo.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'C:\Users\AVI and AMIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zh7w977n\pyexifinfo\pip-egg-info\pyexifinfo.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'C:\Users\AVI and AMIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zh7w977n\pyexifinfo\pip-egg-info\pyexifinfo.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\AVI and AMIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zh7w977n\pyexifinfo\setup.py", line 95, in <module>
    result = check_if_exiftool_is_already_installed()
  File "C:\Users\AVI and AMIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zh7w977n\pyexifinfo\setup.py", line 48, in check_if_exiftool_is_already_installed
    result = subprocess.call(
  File "c:\users\avi and amit\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 340, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "c:\users\avi and amit\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "c:\users\avi and amit\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full 
command output.
```

I would provide the full error log, but I do not know the location of the log file.

Answer (score 0):

`preview-generator` [depends](https://github.com/algoo/preview-generator/blob/7397994d5ac2747a183dff39fd0e02b9b1581198/setup.py#L37) on `pyexifinfo`, and [`pyexifinfo` is a Python wrapper for Exiftool](https://pypi.org/project/pyexifinfo/). So you need to install said [`ExifTool`](https://exiftool.org/) and add it to `%PATH%`.

Comment: Installing exifinfo fixed the initial error, however, a new error has occurred while installing "preview-generator": https://pastebin.com/wjfBv0aX